# Push view instance of controller to NavigationView

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to add navigation in my application. I have some controllers defined in my application so I can reach them by `this.getApplication().getController('SomeController')`. I want to push the view instance of SomeController on my navigationView. This works fine by using `push({xtype: 'someView'})` but in my controller, if I try to change my view, it says it's undefined.

I think this is because the view I've pushed is not the same as the one of my controller. Here's a code sample of my controller:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        someView: {

            selector: '#someView',
            xtype: 'someView'
        }
    },
},
store: null,
setStore: function(){
 //creating store...
 //...
 someView.setStore(this.store);
}
```

And this is my view:

```
Ext.define('EpaMobile.view.SomeView', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
alias: 'widget.someView',
xtype: 'someView',
requires: ['Ext.field.Search', 'Ext.Toolbar'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your view an `itemId` to be used as the selector when referenced in the controller. Also `alias` and `xtype` is the same thing so just stick with the alias and remove the `xtype`. So your view should look like this:

```
Ext.define('EpaMobile.view.SomeView', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    alias: 'widget.someView',
    requires: ['Ext.field.Search', 'Ext.Toolbar'],
    config: {
        ...
        itemId: 'someViewItemId',        
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Lastly modify your `ref` block to this:

```
...
refs: {
    someView: {
        selector: '#someViewItemId',
        xtype: 'someView',
        autoCreate: true
    }
},
...
```

You should now be able to use `push({xtype: 'someView'})` without getting the `undefined` error.